# Display Data from Another Contract in Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, remix

The code compiles well.   But it gives the following error, when event LogData is activated.   LogAddress works well.  Do I have to set up explicit getters for the State Variables?

> transact to browser/Test.sol:Factory.getContract errored: VM error:
>   invalid opcode.   The constructor should be payable if you send value.
>     The execution might have thrown.    Debug the transaction to get more
>   information.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

contract TestContract {

    uint public iD;
    bytes32 public name;
    function setAttr(uint _id, bytes32 _name) {
        iD = _id;
        name = _name;
    }
}

contract Factory {

    TestContract myTest;
    address contractAddress;
    function Factory () {
        myTest = new TestContract();
        myTest.setAttr(100,"0x111");
        contractAddress = address(myTest);
    }

    event LogData(uint _mydata, bytes32 _name);
    event LogAddress(address _add);
    function getContract() {
        myTest = TestContract(contractAddress);
        LogAddress(contractAddress);
        LogData(myTest.iD(), myTest.name());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fiddled with it until it works.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

contract TestContract {

  uint public iD;
  bytes32 public name;
  function TestContract(uint _id, bytes32 _name) public {
    iD = _id;
    name = _name;
  }
}

contract Factory {

  TestContract myTest;
  TestContract testContract;
  function Factory () public {
    testContract = new TestContract(100,"0x123");
  }

  event LogData(uint _mydata, bytes32 _name);
  event LogAddress(address _add);
  function getContract() public {
    LogAddress(testContract);
    LogData(testContract.iD(), testContract.name());
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @RobHitchens, The above changes works now.   I had a follow up question:  In the LogData, Remix throws an error if I change testContract.iD() to testContract.iD.   Do I need to use the default getter?  If the state variable is public - shouldn't I be able to access it directly using testContract.iD.   Remix shows an error "Type Error:  Invalid type of arg. in function call........)

Comment: The "free" 'public' getter for the `iD` is a function, so it needs `()` to access.